# How to count the YTD earn day

Tags: excel-formula

I would like to count the YTD earn day based on their join date and last working date and below is my formula. However, I am facing an issue for those agents joining date this year and left after few days/month and you can see the YTD Earn Day is incorrect as per highlighted red font

I'd appreciate if anyone could advise on how to achieve the same result with the "Expected result Column".

`=IF(D2="",IF(C2<$I$1,$I$2-$I$1,$I$2-C2),IF(D2>=$I$1,D2-$I$1,"Resigned"))+1`

[image]

Comment: What I believe you are encountering is you're looking at the Total Day Difference but looking for the difference in Workdays, instead of saying `D2-$I$1` you should use `NetWorkDays($I$2,D2,[holidays])` However this will require you create a list of the holidays dates that the calculation will skip over and automatically assume no work on weekends.